# How to create an archiving and reading system in Java through serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

This is an exercise question in the book. The title is to design a simple employee information system that can input data and display the input data.
An extension of this exercise requires me to design an save option to output the objects in the array into a tmp file.

I have successfully created the saved options now.
But I think the current method is a bit tedious and requires multiple calls to the method in the class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNGXv.png)

But I can't put the ObjectOutputStream directly in the class, an IOException will occur.
In addition, the next question requires me to create an option to read files.
I don't know how I can import the data directly into the array after reading it.

```
package myJava.exercise.ch12;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ex12_06      
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        CPersonAccount obj = new CPersonAccount();
        char runFunc='d';
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(runFunc!='q')
        {
          System.out.print("請選擇作業");
          System.out.print("(i=輸入資料 s=依月薪資排序 d=顯示資料 q=離開 S=存檔):");
          runFunc = keyboardInput.nextLine().charAt(0);
          switch (runFunc)
          {
            case 'i':
               obj.inputData();
               break;            
            case 's':
               obj.sortBySalary();
               break;
            case 'd':
               obj.displayData();
               break;
            case 'S':
               FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\myJava\\exercise\\ch12\\file\\ex6.tmp");
               ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
               for(int i=0;i<obj.dataNum();i++){
                 os.writeObject(obj.saveName(i));
                 os.writeObject(obj.saveDegree(i));
                 os.writeObject(obj.saveId(i));
                 os.writeObject(obj.saveSalary(i));
              }
              os.close();
              fo.close();
           default:
               break;
          }
        }
   } 
}   

`your text`
class CPersonData{
  public String name;
  public String degree;
  private String p_id;
  private int salary;

  public CPersonData(){
    name = "~~~~~~~~";
    degree = "~~~~~~~~";
    salary = 0;
  }

  public CPersonData(String a,String b,String c,int d){
   name = a;
   degree = b;
   p_id = c;
   salary = d;
  }

  public int getSalary(){
   return salary;
  }

  public String getId(){
    return p_id;
   }

  public void show(){
    System.out.print(name+"\t");
    System.out.print(degree+"\t");
    System.out.println(salary);
  }

}

class CPersonAccount{
  CPersonData personArr[] = new CPersonData[1]; 
  BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String a,b,c;
  int d;

  public CPersonAccount(){}

  public void inputData(){
    for(int i=0;i<personArr.length;i++){
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工姓名");
            a = buf.readLine();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工職別");
            b = buf.readLine();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工ID");
            c = buf.readLine();  
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工薪資");
            d = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine()); 
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      personArr[i] = new CPersonData(a,b,c,d);
    }
  }

  public void displayData(){
    CPersonData tit = new CPersonData();
    tit.show();
    for(int i=0;i<personArr.length;i++){
      System.out.print(personArr[i].name+"\t");
      System.out.print(personArr[i].degree+"\t");
      System.out.println(personArr[i].getSalary());
    }
  }

  public void sortBySalary(){

  }

  public String saveName(int x){
    return personArr[x].name;
  }

  public String saveDegree(int x){
    return personArr[x].degree;
  }

  public String saveId(int x){
    return personArr[x].getId();
  }
  
  public int saveSalary(int x){
    return personArr[x].getSalary();
  }

  public int dataNum(){
    return personArr.length;
  }
}
```

As mentioned before, I tried to put saveData in class CPersonAccount, but an IOException will be displayed.
The original number of materials for the exercises was five strokes. I changed the data to one stroke for the purpose of testing.

I now want to ask if there is any other way to adjust the way I export archives.
Then how should I design the function of reading the archive.

I made some corrections based on the comments.

```
case 'S':
  FileOutputStream fo = new 
  FileOutputStream("C:\\myJava\\exercise\\ch12\\file\\ex6.tmp");
  ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
   for(int i=0;i<obj.dataNum();i++){
       String a = obj.saveName(i);
       String b = obj.saveDegree(i);
       String c = obj.saveId(i);
       int d = obj.saveSalary(i);
       os.writeObject(new CPersonAccount(a,b,c,d));
   }

class CPersonAccount implements Serializable{
  CPersonData personArr[] = new CPersonData[1];
  BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String a,b,c;
  int d;

  public CPersonAccount(){}

  public CPersonAccount(String st1,String st2,String st3,int in4){
    a = st1;
    b = st2;
    c = st3;
    d = in4;
    for(int i=0;i<personArr.length;i++){
      personArr[i]= new CPersonData(a,b,c,d);
    }
  }
```

However, new problems arise with this method.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3z4u.png)

Comment: What happens if you try `os.writeObject(obj);` instead of your several method calls inside the loop?

Comment: unrelated but... **always** close the streams!

Comment: Like this?
os.writeObject(new CPersonAccount(a,b,c,d));   (class CPersonAccount implements Serializable)

Comment: @fantaghirocco I added close the streams.
I forgot to write it (I'm a trainee)

Comment: @LajosArpad Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.BufferedReader <-This is the exception message I am currently experiencing.

Comment: *"(I'm a trainee)"* - OK ... so shouldn't you be asking your trainer / mentor?

Comment: Resources must be closed after use, preferably with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). If that’s not covered by the book, you should dump it and search for a better one.

Comment: @StephenC I am now self-study and practicing following books, so there is no trainer/mentor for me to ask.

Comment: You have correctly added `implements Serializable`. Can you quote the full error when you run the code now?

Comment: @LajosArpad The error message currently running is what is shown in the last picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3z4u.png

Comment: The error message is clear. You can’t store a `BufferedReader` and for whatever reason you have declared one as part of your `CPersonAccount` object. But as said, your code is full of fundamental errors and solving this one problem will not make this code work correctly. As said, if that’s the result of the book’s guidance, you should look for a different book.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: @Holger Because the exercises in this book do not give so many hints, I made adjustments based on the usage of grammar mentioned in each chapter. It is possible that my understanding is not sufficient.

Comment: @Holger It can be completed smoothly until the part that is exported to the tmp file, but I encounter a bottleneck when it comes to reading the tmp file. Even if I make adjustments, new errors appear.

Comment: “Even if I make adjustments, new errors appear”—That’s precisely what I said. It’s not about “completed smoothly”, the code is fundamentally wrong. As already said, resources must be closed correctly, otherwise you can expect corrupted data. Further, it has the logical problem of never producing meaningful data that could be saved. The constructor `public CPersonAccount(String st1,String st2,String st3,int in4){ st1 = a; st2 = b; st3 = c; in4 = d; …` has it backwards, assigning the values of the uninitialized fields to the parameters, not that it matters though, as it is never used anyway…

Comment: @Holger  I would like to ask, in the original code (the part that creates the save option), are there any serious problems with my code? (I saw that it successfully exported the tmp file, but I am not sure if it is correct. )

Comment: @Holger The other part is that I don't quite understand where the error that occurred after the modification originated. I know that he said that the error part lies in BufferedReader.

Comment: @Holger The example of ObjectOutputStream in the book is probably like this:
oos.writeObject(new CMyStubent("ID","name",score1,score2,score3));
public CMyStudents(String...){
  id = str1....
}
I thought about how to modify the example to meet the needs of the exercises, but it seemed that my attempt was in the wrong direction.

Comment: @user23381600 Please do not edit your question to include the answer. Instead post an actual answer *below* your question.

Comment: @Progman OK.Since I have just started using this platform, I will attention to the regulations in the future.

Comment: Since you’re not going to store `CPersonAccount` anymore, don’t declare `implements Serializable` for this class. It still should not contain the `BufferedReader`. You’re reading `System.in` through different objects, a `BufferedReader` and a `Scanner`. Since both have their own buffer, this can lead to data loss. Use a single source object for reading from the same external source instead. Then, while you’re closing the resources now, it’s still preferable to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
package myJava.exercise.ch12;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ex12_07    
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        CPersonAccount obj = new CPersonAccount();
        char runFunc='d';
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(runFunc!='q')
        {
          System.out.print("請選擇作業");
          System.out.print("(i=輸入資料 s=依月薪資排序 d=顯示資料 q=離開 S=存檔 L=讀檔):");
          runFunc = keyboardInput.nextLine().charAt(0);
          switch (runFunc)
          {
            case 'i':
               obj.inputData();
               break;            
            case 's':
               obj.sortBySalary();
               break;
            case 'd':
               obj.displayData();
               break;
            case 'S':
               obj.saveData();
               break;
            case 'L':
               obj.loadData();
               break;
           default:
               break;
          }
        }
   } 
}   

class CPersonData implements Serializable{
  public String name;
  public String degree;
  private String p_id;
  private int salary;

  public CPersonData(){
    name = "~~~~~~~~";
    degree = "~~~~~~~~";
    salary = 0;
  }

  public CPersonData(String a,String b,String c,int d){
   name = a;
   degree = b;
   p_id = c;
   salary = d;
  }

  public int getSalary(){
   return salary;
  }

  public String getId(){
    return p_id;
   }

  public void show(){
    System.out.print(name+"\t");
    System.out.print(degree+"\t");
    System.out.println(salary);
  }

}

class CPersonAccount{
  CPersonData personArr[] = new CPersonData[5];
  BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String a,b,c;
  int d;

  public CPersonAccount(){}

  public void inputData(){
    for(int i=0;i<personArr.length;i++){
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工姓名");
            a = buf.readLine();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工職別");
            b = buf.readLine();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工ID");
            c = buf.readLine();  
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.println("請輸入員工薪資");
            d = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine()); 
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("錯誤,請重新輸入");
        }
      }
      personArr[i] = new CPersonData(a,b,c,d);
    }
  }

  public void displayData(){
    CPersonData tit = new CPersonData();
    System.out.println("姓名"+"\t"+"\t"+"職稱"+"\t"+"\t"+"薪資");
    tit.show();
    for(int i=0;i<personArr.length;i++){
      System.out.print(personArr[i].name+"\t"+"\t");
      System.out.print(personArr[i].degree+"\t"+"\t");
      System.out.println(personArr[i].getSalary());
    }
  }

  public void sortBySalary(){

  }

  public void saveData() throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\myJava\\exercise\\ch12\\file\\ex6.tmp");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);

/*Because the original exercise requires five inputs of information, here I use a for loop to input each item.*/

    for(int i=0;i<personArr.length;i++){
      oos.writeObject(new CPersonData(personArr[i].name,personArr[i].degree,personArr[i].getId(),personArr[i].getSalary()));
    }
    oos.close();
    fo.close(); 
  }
 
  public void loadData() throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\myJava\\exercise\\ch12\\file\\ex6.tmp");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
    for(int i=0;i<personArr.length;i++){
      personArr[i] = (CPersonData)ois.readObject();
    }
    ois.close();
    fi.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).